# Debian RPi distro that can automatically backup itself regularly

Tags: debian, backup

I'm looking for either a complete Raspberry Pi distro or something that I can install on top of a Raspberry Pi distro that can do the following:

-Automatically make backups of itself to either the cloud or onto an attached USB drive so that in the event that the Raspberry Pi's SD card becomes corrupt, the only thing that I will need to do is reinstall the Raspberry Pi distro and execute a restore of all of the contents. The contents that I want to include in the backup needs to include

-- All settings in /etc
-- All apk files that I've installed
-- The /home directory and /opt directory
-- etc.

I would perfer the solution to not require me to install scripts, mess with the cronjob, etc. I would also like the distro to be debian base

I'll primary be using it as an apache webserver.

Thank you!

Jeremiah O'Neal
P.S., I am a programmer and have a good understanding of linux if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools available which backup a running Raspberry as a whole and restore the backup on a new SD card. See [Can a Raspberry Pi be used to create a backup of itself?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/can-a-raspberry-pi-be-used-to-create-a-backup-of-itself?rq=1) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently installed `backintime-gnome` on one of my Pi, and it seems to do what you want.

I also regularly use `rsync` to make a "snapshot" of my system from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that make backups very easy without using tools or creating big scripts or so. But it needs some effort one time to prepare the SD Card. For backups and for development I use the Logical Volume Manager **LVM**.

Then you just make a snapshot and backup it on the running system. This has the advantage that you also can use all the other nice features: just make a snapshot, install software and if you don't like it or if unstable just revert to the snapshot. Or it's useful for disaster recovery when  boot up fails. Then just boot into a snapshot and repair your main installation, and so on. If you like to give it a try then look at [Easy backups and snapshots of a running system with LVM](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85959/79866).