# How can I re-recognize my Raspberry (4 Modell B) display (Bruphny 4.0) like it was recognized per default with a fresh Raspbian Buster install?

Tags: display, raspbian-buster, pi-hole, llvm, wireguard

```
1. Summarizing the problem
```

No display (https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07XPM2ZS3) after LVM tutorial anymore.

```
2. Providing details and any research
```

After using this Tutorial ([Easy backups and snapshots of a running system with LVM](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85958/easy-backups-and-snapshots-of-a-running-system-with-lvm/)) from Ingo (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/79866/ingo) everything was/is fine with my Raspberry (Raspberry Pi 4 Modell B; 4 GB, ARM-Cortex-A72 4 x, 1,50 GHz, 4 GB RAM, WLAN-ac, Bluetooth 5, LAN, 4 x USB, 2 x Micro-HDMI ) with a Raspian Buster, Pi-hole, Wireguard installation beside not having a Bruphny 4.0 display anymore (https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07XPM2ZS3). Still access to the cli. The display is just turning on and off in intervals.

```
3.Describing what I’ve tried
```

Tried to redo the whole LVM installation but came out with the same result. The display is recognized by the Raspian Buster default Installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not make a difference if you run the root filesystem from a primary partition or from a logical volume. The operating system only sees the ext4 filesystem, no matter where it is located. Because you restore a complete backup of the SD Card to the logical volume there should also not be a difference.

The only thing I see is, that the display driver has to load at an early stage that is now done with an **initramfs**, needed to load the LVM driver to access the logical volumes before accessing the root filesystem. So I would check if the display driver is needed in the initramfs and then available there. You can check the contents of the initramfs with:

```
rpi ~$ lsinitramfs -l /boot/initrd.img-4.19.97-v7l+
```

I have also optimized the size of the initramfs by including only listed modules. This it set in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` with option `MODULES=list`. You can try to add most filesystem and all harddrive drivers with:

```
MODULES=most
```

But this will increase the size of the initramfs a lot and you will need enough space on the fat32 boot partition. Play with the other options given for `MODULES=` together with loading modules in `/etc/modules` or `/etc/modules-load.d/`. But be sure to always include the lvm driver, otherwise you are lost with an unbootable system. Don't worry, there is a way to repair it. But better check with lsinitramfs before booting.

**Update:**
*@Lawful* confirmed in a comment that just setting `MOUDULES=most` as described above, was the solution. Obviously this also includes the display driver into the initramfs so it can start early.

Comment: Hi Ingo, I changed the MODULES section of /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf to =most and it worked instantly. Thank you! If you would like I could open another question to let you explain "How I can identify and set the needed module which was missing" to make it work. What do you think about my proposal? Please let me know.

Comment: @Lawful If you like to create a new question with answer then it is a good idea. I would prefer to update this answer with the information from your comment and have a link to it on the original tutorial. So we have it all together in context. Tell me what to do.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Lets update this answer with the information to have it all together.

Comment: The follow-up we may agreed on: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112515/how-i-can-identify-and-set-a-needed-display-module-which-was-missing-on-boot-tim